# Scroll to first highlighted cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet of 1250 line items. At the header I made one cell (I4) to enter the value that I’m looking for. Once clicked enter, the row of matched value in the sheet will be highlighted.

As I have to scroll down to reach it and to enter a value in first cell of the highlighted row, I need something, that selects the first cell of the highlighted row, once I entered the value in cell (I4) and pressed enter.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert your row number here:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = YourRow
```

And if you want to scroll back to Range("A1"), even if your windows is tiled into panes, you may use this:

```
Private Sub ScrollHome()
    Dim i As Integer
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Panes.Count
        ActiveWindow.Panes(i).ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.Panes(i).ScrollColumn = 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an Event in your SHEET code, not MODULE code. It needs to be the `Worksheet_Change` event. This code should work. I included a couple defenses in case a user enters, clears, etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("i4")) Is Nothing Then

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value > 0 Then

            Me.Rows(Target.Value).Select

        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```